# What's the significance of `ng-model` attribute in validation in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, angular-ngmodel

Why do we need to use `ng-model` to make sure that validation works. For instance, in [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/RHerVjzrDOMb5PMBy9RA?p=preview) code if I remove `ng-model` attribute then validation breaks but it works as long as there is `ng-model` attribute no matter what is the `value` of attribute is. So what's the significance of `ng-model` in this case? Why do I have to use though it's value does not make much difference?

Comment: Question really doesn't make much sense. How do you plan to bind user input to the data model without using `ng-model`? Everything in angular revolves around the data model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `ng-model` makes *all* the difference. Not the initial value however, which you are correctly asserting seems to be irrelevant. As soon as you type something into that input box Angular magically assigns the value to the variable assigned to `ng-model`.

Subsequently, the value of `ng-model` is what Angular's validation code is validating! The data has to get from your fingers to the code somehow and that's the `ng-model`.

Let's say you have typed into an input box with `ng-model` on it: "I am so cool."

```
<form ng-controller="SuperController">
  <input ng-model="somethingAwesome" />

  <button ng-click="someAction()">Click me!</button>
</form
```

Inside your controller you can access that value on the `$scope`.

```
function SuperController ($scope) {
  $scope.someAction = function () {
    console.log($scope.somethingAwesome) 
    // "I am so cool."
  }
}
```

If you *set* the value inside your controller.. your input box will display that value.

```
function SuperController ($scope) {
  $scope.somethingAwesome = 'You are so cool!'
}
```

Angular's validation functions read the value of the stuff on your `$scope`, which contains the values of items in your view that have the directive `ng-model`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel